# Can we configure system details in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I would like to configure system details in Jenkins jobs for execution part.
In clear way I have 2 systems, in one system i have started Jenkins server. if i click on build now it is getting started execution in server itself, is there any way to start execution in other system by giving it details.

Thanks,
Chaitanya

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, it sounds like you might be wanting to set up one of your jenkins servers as a build slave. There is a good amount of documentation on that topic under the name "Distributed builds".  For example, see [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds).

Describing the process is too involved for a SO post, but [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines) is a step-by-step guide from the folks at Jenkins.

Comment: Hi, Thanks... when i navigate to slave machine and click on launch, i am getting unable to launch application error. could you help me out